# Unable to open more than one .class file per .jar with JD-Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, jd-eclipse

I'm having trouble (maybe caching issues) with JD-Eclipse plug-in.  In a .jar I can open a .class file Foo and it gets decompiled correctly.  In the same .jar I open a .class file Bar and a new tab gets opened called Bar, but it has the decompiled contents of Foo.

If I go to a different .jar I can successfully decompile one .class file until I get the same behavior where every file from that .jar gets displayed as the first file.

Any thoughts on how to fix this are much appreciated.

```
JDK: 1.7.51
Eclipse Version: Kepler
Eclipse Location: D:
JD-Eclipse Version: 0.1.4
```